# Add new parametric curve object/type using Python

Tags: python, bezier-curves, add-on, opengl

I'm thinking of implementing an add-on (using Python) for Lagrange curves. In short (after an instance has been added), in `Object Mode` there should just be a curve (*i.e. the parametric curve evaluated at a couple of parameter values subsequently connected by line segments*) like a Bézier curve, whereas in `Edit Mode` there should be a control net as well (*similar to the control net of a NURBS curve*) that allows the user to change/modify the curve. In addition, it should be possible to assign a numerical value to each point/vertex and edge of the control net.

My approach would be to draw the curve using `bgl` (*given a polynomial degree, the values assigned to the edges could act as parameter spans, thereby defining Lagrange basis functions — any position on the curve can then be computed as the sum of the control points multiplied by their associated basis functions*). However, I'm not sure how to make the curve into an actual object (*such that it can be selected, saved, ...*). In addition, it should still be possible to change the resolution of the curve at a later time.

Next, how/where to store the control net and additional information? My approach would be to create a mesh for this purpose and store values in a `bmesh` layer. In `Object Mode` this mesh should be hidden. But how to link it to the curve (*changing values re-defines the basis functions which should result in a different curve, likewise moving control points should change the curve*)?

I realize this is a rather comprehensive question -- I'm fairly familiar with `bmesh` but apart from simple scripts I don't have much experience coding things in Blender. Any thoughts on a general workflow (*see steps/outline above*) or references to similar add-ons would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the [motion trail addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/Motion_Trail), it's fully interactive in 3D viewport (with handles you can drag). Note that it's a really complex script, because you need to do everything, from event capturing to processing and OpenGL drawning.

Comment: @CoDEmanX Thanks for the link. Hmm, would you recommend implementing this in C++ instead (and compile a local branch of Blender)?

Comment: It's probably even harder to do in C++, but depends on your programming skills. You will have more control of what you can do and performance should be far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [extra objects addon](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/add_mesh_extra_objects/) that provides a 3d function surface that should help with how to create the mesh.

For the showing the surface in the viewport I would look at [CGCookies retopology tools](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopology-contours). If you watch the [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RR06wjt2rs) you will find they draw a preview over the mesh object before creating the final mesh data.

You might want to look at the [PropertyGroup or Collection types](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.props.html) as a way to add extra data to an object.

There is a chance you may be asking too much for python, maybe you need to consider it as a patch to be added to blenders main source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). Ah, the retopology tool reminded me of the [BSurfaces add-on](http://www.blendernation.com/2011/07/25/review-bsurfaces-3d-spline-mesh-sketching-and-re-topology-add-on/). Yes, the patch approach might make more sense (partially because the description in my question is a much simplified version of the actual project).